# Storing Image Filenames As An Array So I Can Add New Values Without Having To Re-Write The Entire Array - MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, array

I have an image library where I would like to create the functionality where users can create boards of selected images. The boards will essentially be collections of images on the site along a certain theme e.g. a board called 'London' where you create a collection of images based on London (from images that are already in the image library).

The backend runs on PHP/MySQL and I seem to have a hit a problem I've never encountered before - how to store the images filenames as part of an array. Unique image filenames are generated when the images are initially uploaded e.g. 'sjkdwuiw18773.jpeg' and in the separate `images` table, the filename and file extension each have their own column e.g. 'sjkdwuiw18773' and 'jpeg'. For the `boards` table because these images are already stored in the database I can store the filename and file extension all as one string e.g. 'sjkdwuiw18773.jpeg'

When a user creates a board, the columns in the `boards` table so far are the primary key `id` of the board, the `board_name` and a currently empty `board_images` column. It's this third `boards_images` column that I can't get my head around.

```
BoardsTable

| id | board_name | board_images |
```

I'm very conscious that if this is done incorrectly there could be significant performance hit to the site, for instance if someone has a board that includes hundreds (or potentially thousands) of images, re-writing that array each time instead of just adding another value or values seems to be the wrong way of going about it?

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

**Note:** Not using MySQL isn't an option.

Comment: It is _usually_ a bad schema design to have an "array" in a cell.

Comment: You want a second table, where each filename is stored in a separate row and foreign-keyed to the first table